# Subquery based on column in main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for help structuring a SQL query with a subquery on table2 based on a column in table1, but where table1 and table2 have no relation.

something like

```
SELECT name, address, dateCreated,
(SELECT itemId FROM table2 WHERE itemDate BETWEEN dateCreated AND DATEADD(ss,10,dateCreated) as item
FROM table1
```

So for each row 'item' must be selected from table2 based on dateCreated for that row.

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have (apart from the missing right parenthesis)?

Comment: can you give an example of the table? (column structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this below logic? The way tried, will through ERROR if there are more than one records found in table2 against any row from table1.

```
SELECT A.name, 
A.address, 
A.dateCreated,
B.itemId 
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON B.itemDate  BETWEEN A.dateCreated AND DATEADD(ss,10,A.dateCreated)
```

With the above query, you will get N numbers of row for each row in table1 based the logic applied for Date --BETWEEN A.dateCreated AND DATEADD(ss,10,A.dateCreated)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `IF EXISTS` as shown below.

```
SELECT name
    , [address]
    , dateCreated
FROM table1
where exits(
    SELECT itemId 
    FROM table2 WHERE itemDate BETWEEN dateCreated AND DATEADD(ss, 10,dateCreated) and table1.ItemId = table2.ItemId)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, address, dateCreated, table2.itemId 
from table1 LEFT JOIN  table2  WHERE   itemDate BETWEEN dateCreated AND DATEADD(ss,10,dateCreated)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want at most one item from `table2`, then your approach is fine but you want `top (1)`:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.address, t1.dateCreated,
       (SELECT TOP (1) t2.itemId
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.itemDate BETWEEN t1.dateCreated AND DATEADD(second, 10, t1.dateCreated
       ) as item
FROM table1 t1;
```

You can also phrase this as a lateral join, using `outer apply`:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.address, t1.dateCreated,
       t2.itemId
FROM table1 t1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t2.itemId
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.itemDate BETWEEN t1.dateCreated AND DATEADD(second, 10, t1.dateCreated
     ) t2;
```

This makes it easy to select multiple columns.